# php - How to use jquery correctly in .php files? WP-Admin only showing html

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation where I am currently trying to create a formular where after sending the formular I process the data and save it into a mysql DB.

To achieve this I have created a new .php file which I included in the "function.php" of my theme because i want to add the whole formular/process with a shortcode.

The .php file currently contains this (Simplified):

```
function FNC_Add_New_Record ()
{
    $options = "<option value='unselected'>- Select one -</option>"
        . "<option value='option1'>Option 1</option>"
        . "<option value='option2'>Option 2</option>";

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<form id='form1' method='post'>";
    echo "<div style='text-align: center;'>";
    echo "<font size=5>Selection 1</font><br>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='textfield1' placeholder='Insert caption here'><br>";
    echo "<select id='selection1'>" . $options . "</select>";
    echo "<select id='selection2'><option value='unselected'>- No option1 selected -</option></select>";
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "</form>";
    echo "<br>";
}
add_shortcode('FNC_Add_New_Record','FNC_Add_New_Record');
```

Because the selection 2 depends on what is selected with the selection 1 I added jquery to the end of the .php file:

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selection1").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "option1") {
            $("#selection2").html("<option value='none'>None</option><option value='option2'>Option 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "option2") {
            $("#selection2").html("<option value='none'>None</option><option value='option2'>Option 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "unselected") {
            $("#selection2").html("<option value='unselected'>- No option1 selected -</option>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

So, there is probably a lot I have done wrong but this was the only way I was able to get it working. Yes I have searched here and on a lot other sides for proper solutions which tell me to add it to the function.php of the theme and do it with "enqueue". I have tried all of the possible suggest functions and code snippets but nothing worked.

The issue what I have with this solution is that it renders the wp-admin of my wordpress installation useless because it just shows the code which I have added to the .php file as html.

what I get on my site accessing wp-admin:
[image: What I get]

Also i'd like to note that using the tag `"<!DOCTYPE html>"` is a solution to another problem I have when adding jquery but i have no idea if it's the correct solution. If I remove this tag the main navigation of my website, instead of being like 15px in height suddenly has a height of almost a whole full HD screen.

Comment: remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` if you already have that in the html, if you don't then add a `<head>` and `<body>` section also

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but the DOCTYPE tag just prevented my navigation menu from going crazy, the main issue with jquery exists with and without DOCTYPE tag

Comment: you need a valid html construction - https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html Don't even start coding before you realize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress function.php also includes all JS files, make use of `wp_enqueue_scripts` to queue up your scripts.

```
function my_scripts_loader() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myjquerylib-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/myjquerylib.js');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_loader');
```

Comment: I already did this and similar solution but never got one to work. To explain a little bit further (I just tried from scratch): Went to the jquery site and downloaded "jquery-2.2.4.js". Put it into the directory "/wp-content/themes/generatepress/js". Then added following code to the function.php of the theme: 

    `function my_scripts_loader() {

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-2.2.4-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.js' , array( 'jquery' ));

    
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_loader');`

Comment: With `array( 'jquery' )` you're telling the function you require jQuery to load jQuery and since jQuery isnt enqued it wont load jQuery, kind of a paradox, isn't it? Try: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-2.2.4-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.js');`. If a library depends on jQuery add `array('jquery-2.2.4-js');`

Comment: Tried with `array('jquery-2.2.4-js');` and without, but both are not working

Comment: Tried `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-2.2.4-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.js');`? Have you checked if it is getting loaded?

Comment: With `wp_script_is` it is registered + enqueued

Comment: If it still doesn't work your snippet is probably getting loaded before jQuery, enqueue your snippet in a seperate file as well or add it to the footer.

Comment: That's what i was trying right now! And it worked! :)

`function my_scripts_loader() {
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-2.2.4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.2.4.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('NewDungeonRecord', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customfile.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '2.2.4' , true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_loader');`

As far as i know the "true" for the second enqueue is to put it in the footer.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! :) Feel free to accept this as answer